# Rancher Load Balancer - Service is ready:Load balancer is being provisioned

Tags: kubernetes, service, load, rancher

If my Rancher load balancer is stuck on "Pending" for more than 12 hours after creating it, what does it mean?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGhso.png)

Comment: Your are using rancher version kubernetes?

Comment: Yes. I am using Rancher on Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

I would need more information, but my first guess is that the load balancer service ran into an error. What provider are you using? You can view the logs of the failing service in rancher by going to `services` and viewing associated services with the LB.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. We ran out of IP address in the pool. Resized it an she ran.